# Numpy polyval output y has different size than input x

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the square of total error. Given to `polyval` the coefficients of my polynomial and **n** points at which to evaluate it, I expected equal **n** output values. But if you run the code below, output values are less than the size of **x** given as input. I am new in numpy and any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval

x = [ 0.1,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.9 ]
y = [ 0.61,0.92,0.99,1.52,1.47,2.03]
n = len(x)-1

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

for m in range(0,n):

    coef = np.array([])
    A = np.vander(x,x.size)
    A = A[:,n-m-1:n]
    print(A)
    b = np.transpose(y)
    c = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)

    for temp in range(0,c[2]):
        coef = np.append(coef, c[0][temp])

    print(coef)
    print(x)
    yy = polyval(coef,x)
    print(yy)
    #E = sum(((y-yy)**2))
```

The desired output would be:
1 Iteration.
c =
   1.76456
   0.28616

x =
   0.10000   0.40000   0.50000   0.70000   0.70000   0.90000

yy =
   0.46262   0.99198   1.16844   1.52135   1.52135   1.87426

2 Iteration.
c =
   1.729547
   0.059092
   0.587116

x =
   0.10000   0.40000   0.50000   0.70000   0.70000   0.90000

yy =
   0.61032   0.88748   1.04905   1.47596   1.47596   2.04123

And goes on until 6....

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html) is not the same function as [`numpy.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html).  The two functions have the polynomial and `x` arguments reversed, and when you use the coefficients as the polynomial argument, the two functions have opposite conventions for the order of the coefficients.

Comment: Oh you are so right I didn't notice that difference. Thank you so much that fixed it :)